# Mysql queries issue

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 3 tables in my mysql DB to query.

[image]

- **Users_rates** (fields: id,userid,raterid,rate,eventid) containing all of the rates(rate) that have been assigned to users(userid), participating to specific events(eventid), by other users(raterid)
- **Events_participants** (fields:id,userid,eventid) containing all of the users(userid) participating to each event(eventid)
- **Users** (fields:id,name,lastname)containing all the user relative data

I need to query those three tables to retrieve an event-specific rank for the users' rates.

Ex. John,Erik and Mark  participated to 'eventid=31'.
John received 1 rate from Mark, and 2 from Erik.
Mark received 1 rate from Erik.
Nobody has rated Erik though.

I need to retrieve for each user name,lastname and the sum of the rates received for eventid=31

I tried with this:

```
SELECT events_participants.userid,users.name,users.lastname,
(SELECT SUM(rate)FROM users_rates WHERE users_rates.eventid=31 AND users_rates.userid=events_participants.userid)AS rate 
FROM(( events_participants INNER JOIN users ON events_participants.userid=users.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_rates ON events_participants.userid=users_rates.userid )
WHERE events_participants.eventid=31
```

But I receive:

```
userid | name | lastname | rate  

1 | luca | silvestro | 1 

3 | claudio | buricchi | 6

3 | claudio | buricchi | 6
```

What's the right query?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.userid, users.name, users.lastname, temp.sum as rate
FROM users LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userid, SUM(rate) as sum FROM users_rates WHERE eventid = 31 GROUP BY userid
) as temp USING (userid)
```

It might give an error, this might work instead:

```
SELECT users.userid, users.name, users.lastname, temp.sum as rate
FROM users, (
    SELECT userid, SUM(rate) as sum FROM users_rates WHERE eventid = 31 GROUP BY userid
) as temp WHERE users.userid = temp.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the problem right, but maybe something like:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname, SUM(ur.rate) AS rate
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN users_rates AS ur ON ur.userid = u.id
WHERE ur.eventid = 31
GROUP BY u.id
```

**edit**: If you want to receive a list with all users regardless of whether they have any rates at all, you could also join the `users_participants` table and replace the `INNER JOIN` of `users_rates` by a `LEFT JOIN`. The `WHERE` clause has to reference `events_participants` then (not `users_rates` anymore as it could be `NULL`):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname, SUM(ur.rate) AS rate
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN events_participants AS ep ON ep.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN users_rates AS ur ON ur.userid = u.id AND ur.eventid = ep.eventid
WHERE ep.eventid = 31
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: what if I need to retrieve a list of all of the users partecipating to the event even if they didnt receive yet a rate (so they're not in the users_rates table)??

Comment: Then you have to also join the `events_participants` table and replace the `INNER JOIN` by a `LEFT JOIN`. I'll edit my post in this direction.